# Can't find glGenBuffers,glBindBuffer etc. in qopenglfunctions.h

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glsl

I am trying to write a map application in qt 5.1.1 rendered with opengl using shaders.
I am able to display the vertices using Glew. But I would like to use the functions provided in qopenglfunctions.h
What is weird is that even when I include this file, I get glGenBuffers was not declared in this scope. When I open qopenglfunctions.h, it's sitting right there in that file!
Any one come across this weird issue? The code is quite a bit long. But I have added some which throws the linker error.

```
initializeGLFunctions();
this->program=program;

glGenVertexArrays(1,&mapVAO); //This is where the linker throws an error
glBindVertexArray(mapVAO);

// Generate 2 VBOs
glGenBuffers(2, mapBuffer);
initMapBoundary();


void GeometryEngine::initMapBoundary()
{
     GLfloat mapSize=5.0f;
  VertexData boundary[] = {
    // Vertex data for face 0
    {QVector3D(-mapSize, -mapSize,  1.0), QVector2D(0, 0)},  // v0
    {QVector3D( mapSize, -mapSize,  1.0), QVector2D(20.0,0/*0.33, 0.0*/)}, // v1
    {QVector3D(-mapSize,  mapSize,  1.0), QVector2D(0,20/*0.0, 0.5*/)},  // v2
    {QVector3D( mapSize,  mapSize,  1.0), QVector2D(20.0,20.0/*0.33, 0.5*/)}, // v3
};


GLushort indices[] = {
    0,  1,  2,  3,
};


// Transfer vertex data to VBO 0
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mapBuffer[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * sizeof(VertexData), boundary, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Transfer index data to VBO 1
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mapBuffer[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * sizeof(GLushort), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Offset for position
quintptr offset = 0;

// Tell OpenGL programmable pipeline how to locate vertex position data
int vertexLocation = program->attributeLocation("a_position");
program->enableAttributeArray(vertexLocation);
// program->setAttributeBuffer(vertexLocation,GL_FLOAT,offset,3);
glVertexAttribPointer(vertexLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), (const void *)offset);

// Offset for texture coordinate
offset += sizeof(QVector3D);

// Tell OpenGL programmable pipeline how to locate vertex texture coordinate data
int texcoordLocation = program->attributeLocation("a_texcoord");
program->enableAttributeArray(texcoordLocation);
glVertexAttribPointer(texcoordLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), (const void *)offset);
//program->setAttributeBuffer(texcoordLocation,GL_FLOAT,offset,2);
}
```

Like I said, all this is working fine on my linux box so I am sure there's nothing much wrong with the code. I just need to know how to tell the qt build system to choose the correct opengl driver on a windows (7) machine. Graphics card Nvidia GT325m

Comment: You might need to add `#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES` to your file that includes it.

Comment: Can you paste a minimal snippet showing the issue?

Comment: @JesusRamos, I already did that. Didn't seem to work. By the way the issue was opengl version ( as mentioned by Michael IV in one of the answers). I am using archlinux's qt5 build with mesa drivers. I finally used glew to get what I needed. My laptop is too weak to be able to handle building qt from sources.

Comment: Building qt from source will just take a while, shouldn't crash I don't think.

Comment: It doesn't crash. Like I said, my laptop is too old and it heats up and turns off while building.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Qt 5 it won't work for you the regular way. The problem is that the pre compiled Qt SDK ( which you probably got from their website)  uses GLES 2.0 backend for GL rendering enabled by default. That means, your glew headers will get all sort of errors related to similar declarations in qopenglfunction header. Unfortunately for you, you will have to rebuild Qt sources with opengl  -desktop command which Will remove ES2.0 dependence for you.Another way is to use Qt 4.8 version.

Comment: I am sorry I wasn't clear, I am well aware of the GLES 2.0 backend with Qt on linux.(And I did build qt with the opengl -desktop option on my linux box). However, the issue is on my friend's laptop which has windows. He downloaded the prebuilt binary from qt's website which comes bundled with opengl. So the problem is with the drivers on windows.

Comment: At least on windows, the Qt binary installer offers two versions, one with desktop OpenGL and one with ANGLE.